# I want to upload an image URL to my angular form as json data and send it to server. the image URL is from the server response

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, angular6, httpclient

I want to upload an image URL to my angular form as json data and send it to server. the server should respond the image URL.
that because the server rename the image, I want to get the URL of the image from the server and then put it in the my form and then submit the form to server. 
 
this is image upload to server:

```
selectedFile: File = null;

onFileSelected(event){
 this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
}

onUpload(){
 const fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('imageFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
 this.http.post('https://localhost:3443/products/upload', fd)
   .subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res);
   });
 }
```

and this is my form

```
 createForm() {
  this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  imgFront: [''],
  imgBack: [''],
});
```

and this is the json data

```
{
  "name": "new product",
  "imgFront": "images/products/0.7578449276506667Photo.png",
  "imgBack": "images/products/0.44058320485375324WhatsApp Image 2018-10-25 at 18.00.23.jpeg",

},
```

Comment: And what did you try ? We're not here to code for you, show us what you have tried and what doesn't work, as explained in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, files are not considered as a part of the form. They are added to the `form` but then handled differently. The reason is that file uploads are generally meant to be async and in most of the cases, aren't generally uploaded on form submit.

Instead, they are uploaded first and then their download URLs are added to the form value, just the way you want them.

So to handle your case, you can do the following:

1. Remove `imgFront` and `imgBack` from your `productForm`.
2. Declare `imgFront` and `imgBack` properties on your Component.
3. Disable the `Submit` button from the form unless the `imgFront` and `imgBack` are set.
4. Once they are set, enable the submit button.
5. While sending the response to the product API, add the `imgFront` and `imgBack` to the request payload as well.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-with-file-upload?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: @HamzaHajyousef, I'm glad it did. Please also consider accepting this as an answer to close the loop. :) Happy Coding.